# Accessing the bool data type in printf in the C language

Tags: c, boolean, initialization, printf, implicit-conversion

What if I want to print a `bool` var value, but I used `%f` and `%s` in the printf format string?  How does the code work?

```
bool a = true;
bool b = "true";
bool c = '\0';
bool d = "\0";
printf("%d\n", a);
printf("%d\n", b);
printf("%d\n", c);
printf("%d\n", d);
printf("%s\n", a);
printf("%s\n", b);
printf("%s\n", c);
printf("%s\n", d);
printf("%f\n", a);
printf("%f\n", b);
printf("%f\n", c);
printf("%f\n", d);
```

Comment: This is my first Question on stackoverflow so the unconventional method of writing must be excused

Comment: You are forgiven. Will probably be fixed in a minute

Comment: I excuse the unconventional writing in the initial version. Now please [edit] and change according to [ask] and using this info for proper formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help And if you do not want to rely on being excused by everybody, better delete the question while you do the editing. Then undelete it later. Good luck.

Comment: *"How does the code work?"* - Very bad

Answer (score 2):

The name `bool` is a macro name for the standard unsigned integer type `_Bool`.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 6. ...The type _Bool and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer types are the standard unsigned integer
>    types

and (7.18 Boolean type and values <stdbool.h>)

> 2 The macro bool expands to _Bool.
> 3 The remaining three macros are suitable for use in #if preprocessing
> directives. They are `true` which expands to the integer constant `1`,
> `false` which expands to the integer constant `0`,...

And objects of the type `_Bool` may have only one of two values (6.2.5 Types)

> 2 An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values
> 0 and 1.

The following conversions of expressions to the type `_Bool` take place (6.3.1.2 Boolean type)

> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
> value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

In your code snippet there are initialized objects of the type `_Bool`

```
bool a =true;
bool b ="true";
bool c ='\0';
bool d ="\0";
```

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 11 The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,
> optionally enclosed in braces. **The initial value of the object is
> that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints
> and conversions as for simple assignment apply**, taking the type of
> the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type

and (6.5.16.1 Simple assignment)

> 1 One of the following shall hold:
> ....
> — the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool,
> and the right is a pointer.

These two declarations

```
bool a =true;
bool c ='\0';
```

are equivalent to

```
bool a = 1;
bool c = 0;
```

Pay attention to that the integer character constant `'\0'` in C has the type `int` while in C++ it has the type `char`.

And these two declarations are equivalent to

```
bool b = "true" != 0;
bool d ="\0" != 0;
```

That is in these declarations the string literals are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements values of which are not equal to 0. So in fact the above two declarations may be rewritten like

```
bool b = 1;
bool d = 1;
```

These calls of `printf`

```
printf("%d\n",a);
printf("%d\n",b);
printf("%d\n",c);
printf("%d\n",d);
```

are correct. There are outputted values of unsigned integer type _Bool that are implicitly converted to the type `int` using the conversion specifier `d`.

All other calls of `printf` are incorrect because there are used the conversion specifier `s` designed to output strings instead of integers and the conversion specifier `f` is designed to output objects of the type double instead of integers

```
printf("%s\n",a);
printf("%s\n",b);
printf("%s\n",c);
printf("%s\n",d);
printf("%f\n",a);
printf("%f\n",b);
printf("%f\n",c);
printf("%f\n",d);
```

So these calls invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change your approach.
Instead of trying to force all kinds of values into a `bool` variable (whatever `bool` you are using....), you should use variables with appropriate type for what you are trying to store in there. E.g. `'\0'` goes into a variabe of type `char`.

Then, when you want to print the value, it is not a problem to use the formatting specifier which matches that value and variable data type.

When you want to use those values as boolean (which basically you cannot do directly) you create a condition on a boolean expression like `if('\0' == myCharBool)` and in the two `{}else{}`branches of that `if` you do whatever are the possioble outcomes of true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Rememebr that in C, `0` is false. Everything else is true. From `stdbool.h`, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.

So in your examples, `b` is true, because the string literal decays to a pointer to its first element. This will not be `0`. `c` is false, because `'\0'` *is* `0`. `d` is true because again, we're assigning a pointer to the string literal `"\0"`.

When you print, you should get a long string of warnings corresponding to every attempt to print an integer type (`bool`) as something other than an integer. It *might* actually work, but you're well into the realm of undefined behavior.

Realistically, you're unlikely to ever print a `bool` directly in a non-trivial program. You will use it to determine what you do want to print.